# Can my employer see my Google Search Data on my personal IOS device when I’m at home but accidentally logged into company Google Account?

Tags: google

I was browsing the web at home using Safari on my IOS device (mainly Google search). I happened to scroll to the very bottom of the screen and realized Google was logged into my Google account for work. It has probably been like that for a very long time, but I am wondering whether or not my employer can see all the things I’ve searched for on Google while on my phone at home.

Comment: If you were signed into the work Google account when browsing those things & your company uses Google Business then yes they can see what you were browsing when logged in as with the Google business dashboard you can access that data. However; if you're just on your home computer NOT logged into the business account you're safe as they have no control over that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I was logged in on my phone, but at home on my home network. They can still see my Google browsing data even though I’m at home on my own network? I went to myactivity.google.com to check my search history but all I saw were YouTube videos I played while at work on my desktop. There wasn’t any history or search history at all.

Comment: Well; I know that on Google Business you can check search history of the accounts like you can on normal Google. Search history is tied to Google accounts, a Google Business account is essentially the same as your typical account just aimed at businesses. In the dashboard, you can look at the activity on the accounts. Even if you're on your home network if you're logged into the account Google is logging those searches from the admin page they will be able to check account activity.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter what Internet connection you use or what device you use, the fact that you are using the company's account means that they could review all your activity on that account.